# What is this action on computer windows called, "expanding the window"?

Tags: word-request, terminology

When pressing on the the double squares on the right upper corner of browsers (Chrome, Explorer, Firefox etc.) or office word, power-point, or almost any window in computers, can I refer it as **expanding** the window?

> "Please, **expand** the screen by clicking on the double squares" would be
>   correct?

I'm not sure if this is the verb used to describe what I mentioned.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use "expand". But that's a broad term. The specific term for this action is **maximize**. This is when the window "expands" to cover the entire screen.

Two related terms are **minimize** and **restore**. When you shrink and hide the window by clicking the `_` button, you **minimize** the window. When it's hidden and you bring it back, that's called **restoring** the window.

By the way, I call them **windows**, not screens. I'm not sure if "screens" is acceptable. Also, the "on" is not necessary, and, as @amI points out, the double squares "restore down" (also "[restore](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/restore.htm)" or "[unmaximize](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-windows-maximize.html.en)") the window. The single square maximizes the window. So if you want to maximize the window, you could say

> Please, ***maximize*** the **window** by clicking the **single square**

Anyway, these are the terms I know as a Windows user. You can see their usage in these pages:

- [Direct shortcut for Windows Maximize/Minimize/Restore window?](https://superuser.com/questions/988554/direct-shortcut-for-windows-maximize-minimize-restore-window)
- [Maximize](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/maximize.htm)
- [Maximize a Window From the Keyboard](https://www.pcworld.com/article/164234/keyboard_shortcuts.html)

Comment: On MacOS, if you double-click anywhere in the title bar, the window "expands" to fill the width of the screen. But if you click the "maximize" icon, it goes into "full-screen mode." So yes, I think there is a difference between an expanded window and a maximized window.

Comment: Would you like to write that up in an answer?

Comment: My answer would say pretty much what you're saying. "Expand" is a broad term that is not incorrect. "Maximize" is a more accurate term.

Comment: "when you it shirks and hides" was probably intended to be something like "when you shrink a window to hide it". ("shirk" is a verb, and "hide" can be used intransitively, but both seem to be anthropomorphizing the window and the grammar is awkward in the original phrase too.)

Comment: but it's a *single* square that you click to maximize.  Clicking the double (overlapping) squares on a maximized window will 'restore down' to its original size.

Comment: "when you it shirks and hides"  - Yoda the building just has left :)